# Edit ASP.NET GridView Cell on mouse over

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, gridview

in my Project there is Asp.net GridView ( that putted into a update panel).
i did open Gridview In Jquery Ui Dialog.
Is there any way exist to edit a specific column grid View cells in microwave on mouse over on that cell?
for example displaying a div on that position and doing an action.
please give me help.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **hover** jQuery function:

```
$(selector).hover( handlerIn(eventObject), handlerOut(eventObject) )
```

it takes 2 parameters:
1). Function which called on mouse goes in element
2). Function which called on mouse goes out element

In the first parameter you could show div, and hide it in the second one.

Comment: what should i put instead "Selector" ? i want to affect function on cells of a column .

Comment: Something like this: 
"#tableId td:nth-child(2)", where '2' is a number of a column.
I didn't test it, but it should work.